# Failed to install Platformio IDE in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

### Problem

- I'm using platformio IDE in vscode.
- Before 2019.10.11, the platformio IDE extension worked well.
- But after 2019.10.11, every time I open vscode I get this message.

```
Installing PlatformIO Core...
Please do not close this window and do not open other folders until this process is completed.
Failed to install PlatformIO IDE.
```

- No more information shows.

### What I Have Tried

- Uninstall vscode and reinstall it
- Uninstall platformio IDE and reinstall it
- Downgrade vscode from 1.39 to 1.37
- Downgrade platfotmio IDE from 1.90 to 1.83
- pip --no-cache-dir install -U platformio
- conda install platformio
- pip uninstall platform and then pip install platformio
- Restart the computer
- Uninstall platformio IDE and delete all the folders and files whose names contain 'platformio', and than reinstall platformio
- Run vscode as administrator and install platformio IDE
- I still haven't fixed the problem now.

### What I Have Found

- After I uninstall platformio IDE and tried to reinstall it (of course I failed), I found the folder "C:\Users\Bowman.platformio"'s size is only 0KB, and it contains only one folder ".cache".

### What I Have Installed in My Computer

- Anaconda(Python 3.7)
- JDK
- node.js
- .NET Core
- mingw64
- Visual Studio 2019
- Visual Studio 2017
- Stm32CubeIDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good afternoon.

I had exactly the same issue.
Did pretty much the same topics you described.
For me it was related to the anaconda software.

I uninstalled anaconda, uninstall/reinstall platformio in the visual studio environment and it worked.

I got the message that the platformio service was already started and that got me thinking.

regards

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found the problem. My conda's version is 4.7.12, it seems to have some bugs and report "[WinError 127] the specified procedure could not be found" when installing or updating a package. Downgrade conda and the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Today I tried and (initially) failed to install PlatformIO on a Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon machine. VSCode V1.61.2 was freshly installed, Python3 was installed.

Trying to install PlatformIO told me that the Python on the machine was not suitable and installation failed.

After enabling Developer mode in VSCode (Help | Toggle Developer Tools) and trying the install again, I found an error message that told me that the distutils package for Python was missing.

That is because I had not installed pip3.

In the terminal, run `sudo apt install python3-pip`

That gets you the appropriate packages and then PlatformIO will install properly.

Answer (score 0):

thats no big deal i had the same issue....just go to **help > Toggle developers and in that press console** and search platformIo that will show the error most likely with python installation ...you might wants to install some packages manually....
i was using ubuntu...so python packages conflicts...